# Scientific Linux 7 BIND not forwarding

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, bind, forwarding

I installed named-chroot and configured it for the internal network. Everything works great, but nothing gets forwarded.

Here is my configuration:

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.0.15; };
    #listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory       "/var/named";
    dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { clients; };
    notify master-only;
    transfers-in 30;
    auth-nxdomain no;
    empty-zones-enable yes;
    allow-recursion { clients; };
    allow-transfer { localhost; };
    forwarders { 194.15.215.236; 194.15.215.237; 194.15.215.2; };
    recursion yes;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;
    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

#zone "localhost" {
#        type master;
#        file "standard/localhost";
#        allow-transfer { localhost; };
#};

zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "standard/loopback";
        allow-transfer { localhost; };
};

#zone "1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa" {
#        type master;
#        file "standard/loopback6.arpa";
#        allow-transfer { localhost; };
#};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

I also searched on Google a lot, disabled DNSSEC, etc. I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Is that the whole configuration? There's a mentions in allow-query and allow-recursion to the "clients" acl but there is no definition of that acl. Besides that, what kind of error do you get? Can you dig 194.15.215.236, 194.15.215.237 and 194.15.215.2; from the host where you have bind running?

Answer (score 1):

I shortened the config a bit.

Problem was, that disabling DNS Sec was persistent on proxy. After keppen DNS Sec turned off for several minutes, the proxy recognized it.

Thanks!